# Filter out dictionary removing duplicates

Tags: python, list

New to python, I have the following dictionary and to get out a dictionary form this which will contain no duplicate but if duplicate found then data must be append to first key and value.
for example, in 41 has duplicate and has pending = 1 and delivered 14. i want to make such list from this that it contains only one row for 41 and contians count for pending and delivered and plus of these two status.

```
    temp = [
(41, 1, 2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670, 'Pending'), 
(37, 1, 2015-1-21 13:56:3.632057, 'Delivered'), 
(41, 14, 2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670, 'Delivered'), 
(36, 1, 2015-1-21 13:22:52.705818, 'Delivered'), 
(40, 2, 2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670, 'Delivered'), 
(38, 1, 2015-1-21 14:4:10.206100,, 'Delivered')
]
```

first column is id, 2nd is count for status and status is pending, delivered, failed.

if want to make dictionary from these like this

```
dict = {id : { id : id, Pending : pending_count, Failed : failed_count, Delivered : delivered_count, total : pending+failed+delivered, date-time : date-time}}
```

like

```
dict = { 
id : { 'id' : 41, 'Pending' : 1, 'Failed' : 0, 'Delivered' : 14, 'total' : 15, 'date time' : 2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670},
id : { 'id' : 37, 'Pending' : 0, 'Failed' : 0, 'Delivered' : 1, 'total' : 1, 'date-time' : 2015-1-21 13:56:3.632057}
}
```

Comment: What you're showing is not a dictionary but a list of tuples.  Please, at the very least!, show what result you'd desire from processing this (maybe give a better example with more "duplicates" in item [0] of those tuples)...!

Comment: means.. date will be same for all duplicate ID (e.g. 41) ??
Can you give more information on output?? Value of key in dictionary is list???

Comment: You cannot have a dict with duplicate keys, so your end result is not possible.

Comment: the final dict will not have duplicate key, have look at the desired result in dict again.

Comment: ok, you changed output, I will update my solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As input list has constant structure. Elements of list  are `tuple`.
So first item i.e. `id` inside every `tuple` is `key` for output dictionary and value of output dictionary is again dictionary.

1. Iterate every item from `temp` list.
2. Get all count and assign to respect count according to status. used `if` statement for that.
3. If key is present in the output dictionary then update existing values from i.e. update all count value and also total and date value.
4. If not present then add in the output dictionary.
5. Used try except to handle exception i.e. when key is not present in output dictionary.

code:

```
import pprint

temp = [
(41, 1, "2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670", 'Pending'), 
(37, 1, "2015-1-21 13:56:3.632057", 'Delivered'), 
(41, 14, "2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670", 'Delivered'), 
(36, 1, "2015-1-21 13:22:52.705818", 'Delivered'), 
(40, 2, "2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670", 'Delivered'), 
(38, 1, "2015-1-21 14:4:10.206100", 'Delivered')
]

output = {}
for i in temp:
    id = i[0]
    count = i[1]
    date_v = i[2]
    status = i[3]
    p_count = 0
    d_count = 0
    f_count = 0
    if status=="Pending":
        p_count = count
    elif status=="Delivered":
        d_count = count
    elif status=="Failed":
        f_count= count

    try:
        output[i[0]]["Pending"] = output[i[0]]["Pending"]+p_count
        output[i[0]]["Failed"] = output[i[0]]["Failed"]+f_count
        output[i[0]]["Delivered"] = output[i[0]]["Delivered"]+d_count
        output[i[0]]["total"] = output[i[0]]["Pending"]+count
        output[i[0]]["date time"] = date_v
    except KeyError, e:
        total = count
        output[i[0]] = {'id':id, 'Pending':p_count, 'Failed':f_count,\
                        'Delivered':d_count, 'total':total, 'date time':date_v}


pprint.pprint(output)
```

output:

```
{36: {'Delivered': 1,
      'Failed': 0,
      'Pending': 0,
      'date time': '2015-1-21 13:22:52.705818',
      'id': 36,
      'total': 1},
 37: {'Delivered': 1,
      'Failed': 0,
      'Pending': 0,
      'date time': '2015-1-21 13:56:3.632057',
      'id': 37,
      'total': 1},
 38: {'Delivered': 1,
      'Failed': 0,
      'Pending': 0,
      'date time': '2015-1-21 14:4:10.206100',
      'id': 38,
      'total': 1},
 40: {'Delivered': 2,
      'Failed': 0,
      'Pending': 0,
      'date time': '2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670',
      'id': 40,
      'total': 2},
 41: {'Delivered': 14,
      'Failed': 0,
      'Pending': 1,
      'date time': '2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670',
      'id': 41,
      'total': 15}}
```

Comment: Your solution is quite close but have a look at the desired dictionary I want.

Comment: ok let me know if you need more help. You can reach to me by email(vivekbsable@gmail.com)  and skype (vivek.igp) also

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for row in temp:
  result = d[row[0]]
  result[row[-1]] = result.setdefault(row[-1], 0) + row[1]
  result['total'] = result.setdefault('total', 0) + row[1]
  result['{}-date'.format(row[-1])] = row[2]
```

For `d[41]`, this will give you:

```
{'Delivered': 14,
 'total': 15,
 'Pending-date': '2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670',
 'Pending': 1,
 'Delivered-date': '2015-1-22 12:37:58.631670'}
```